# space between two columns div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code. Can someone please suggest the right way to give space between two column classes ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>

.row {
    clear: both;
}

.column {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1 Using margin (Recommended way)

```
.column {
   margin: 10px; /* or what ever */
}
```

#### 2 Using Line Breaks (Not recommended)

Using this:

```
<div class="column"></div>
<br />
<div class="column"></div>
```

#### 3 Padding (that you're using)

Padding would add a space inside the element. Which won't do the trick. You need to use margin instead of padding.

Comment: You're better off using percentages for margin, or you're going to have to do some calculating. You'll also need to change the widths of the columns to account for the margin. Padding will work as long as you don't use borders on the columns. Line breaks will not work ... at all.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div...></div> <div...></div>
```

if that does not work or has a compatibility issue

then try:

```
<div class="column" id="1"></div>
<div class="column" id="2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.column#1{position:fixed/relative/absolute;left: #px or #% ;top: #px or #%;}
```

note: ".column" is the class; the "#1" is the id; position should have only one of the listed values and there may be a few others; Left defines the # of px or % from the left of the document; and top defines the # of px or % from the Top of the document;

**NOTE:**I have only tested this method with Firefox. so other browsers may have other parameters.